# WP8 C# browser style keybaord

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox, windows-phone

I am trying to make an alternative browser for Windows Phone 8 and would like to have the same keyboard open for my textbox as the one used by the native browser. The one with the .com button as well as the arrow where the enter button is. I am guessing this is probably some simple setting but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the URL input scope. See more here: [InputScopeNameValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use [InputScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property in the TextBox, take a look to this [samples in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521152%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

For example:

```
<TextBox Name="txtPhoneNumber" Height="71" Width="460" > 
    <TextBox.InputScope> 
        <InputScope> 
            <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" /> 
        </InputScope> 
    </TextBox.InputScope> 
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Note you can set the the `InputScope` property on the TextBox directly without using the verbose property element syntax.